# How to iterate every rows of a dataframe and make calculations based on other table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iterated-function

I have a dataframe like this basically:

- table1:
  Every market has 2 groups and it is a 2 years data. I want to make new data table based on several conditions.

| date | market | group | cost | income | clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A | R | .... | .... | ..... |
|  | A | N |  |  |  |
|  | B | R |  |  |  |
|  | B | N |  |  |  |
|  | C | R |  |  |  |
|  | C | N |  |  |  |

I created this table by market and its groups:

```
table2 = table1.groupby(["market", "group"])[["cost"]].sum().reset_index()
```

| market | group | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | R | ..... |
| A | N |  |
| B | R |  |
| B | N |  |
| C | R |  |
| C | N |  |

I want to create new table by iterating every row and create a new column based on:
If cost < 1000 then I want to go with market with its own group in table1, then sum income and divide by clicks.
If cost > 1000 then I want it to be 0.

| market | group | cost | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | R | ..... |  |
| A | N |  |  |
| B | R |  |  |
| B | N |  |  |
| C | R |  |  |
| C | N |  |  |

I tried this:

```
for index, row in table2.iterrows():
    if row['cost'] < 1000:
        table2['new_column'] = table1.loc[(table1.market == row['market'] & (table1.group == row['group'])]['income'].sum() / table1.loc[(table1.market == row['market'] & (table1.group == row['group'])]['clicks'].sum()
    else:
        table1['new_column'] = 0
```

I just want to iterate every row and go to the first table with values of the second table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's faster to sum up all 3 columns `cost`, `income` and `clicks` and then set a condition for `new_column`:

```py
table2 = table1.groupby(["market", "group"]).sum()
table2["new_column"] = np.where(table2["cost"] > 1000, 0, table2["income"] / table2["clicks"])
```

You can drop the unneeded columns after.

Comment: Thank you very much but what about if I have 3 conditions?  Because it can be in the next step and I don't know how to use in the 'where'.

Comment: Use `np.select`